# apt-get equivalent of this command

Tags: apt, package-management

I'd like to know the equivalent of the

```
dnf remove *nvidia*
```

with the `apt` package manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be:

```
sudo apt-get remove '.*nvidia.*'
```

This will remove all packages that contain the string `nvidia` in their names.

If you want to remove the configuration files too, use `purge`:

```
sudo apt-get purge '.*nvidia.*'
```

---

Note that, for this kind of operation, you should do a `--dry-run` first:

```
sudo apt-get --dry-run remove '.*nvidia.*'
```

Comment: thanks i didn't knew the '--dry-run' option. Thumbs up